# Disabling time is not working in pickadate.js

Tags: javascript, pickadate

I'm trying to integrate [pickadate.js](https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/) on my project but unfortunately after reading the documentation, I'm having difficulty on how I can disable a specific time

```js
$(function() {
    let $timePicker = $('input').pickatime()
  
  let timePicker = $timePicker.pickatime('picker')
  
  timePicker.set('disable', new Date(2021,5,22,9))
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/themes/classic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/themes/classic.time.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="time">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/picker.time.js"></script>
```

. Please see my code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello refer to [this](https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-disable-enable-times)  you can use arrays formatted [Hours,Minutes] but the problem within your code is that you didnt pass an array as second param to the timepicker set() method . look at the snippet below i edited yours

```js
timePicker.set('disable', [

  // Using a collection of arrays formatted as [HOUR,MINUTES]
  [2,30], [4,30], [9,0],

  // Using JavaScript Date objects
  new Date(2015,9,13,6), new Date(2015,9,13,12,30)
])
picker.set('enable', [
  [4,30], [6,0],
  new Date(2015,9,13,9)
])
```

```js
$(function() {
    let $timePicker = $('input').pickatime()
  
  let timePicker = $timePicker.pickatime('picker')
  
  timePicker.set('disable', [new Date(2021,5,22,9)])
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/themes/classic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/themes/classic.time.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="time">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.2/picker.time.js"></script>
```